# How to save custom fields in Firestore during signing up for the first time?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using Email Authentication for signing up users. I want a Collection of users with their UID as the document name. Each document contains the Name and the email ID of the user. 
In order to achieve this I've tried doing this,

```
public void addUser(View view){
    progressDialog.setMessage("Adding Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();


    final String name = String.valueOf(etName.getText());
    final String email = String.valueOf(etEmail.getText());
    String password = String.valueOf(etPassword.getText());

    Map<String,Object> faculty = new HashMap<>();
    faculty.put("name", name);
    faculty.put("email", email);

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(AddFaculty.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        //display some message here
                        Toast.makeText(AddFaculty.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        reference = firestore.collection("faculty").document(uid);
        reference.set(faculty);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This method gets called when the Signup button is clicked.
The problem here is that the "DATA ADDED" toast is shown, but the data is not being saved.
But the data is saved if I hardcode the Document name instead of passing the UID of the user, eg:

```
reference = firestore.collection("faculty").document(uid); //Doesn't work
reference = firestore.collection("faculty").document("user_id") //Works perfectly
```

This issue has been bothering me for almost a week now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is not `null`?

Comment: Have you tried moving the database writing code inside the onsucces of your create user?

Comment: I don't see how the "Data added" toast would appear at all.  You're checking for the user before it's actually been created.  I would expect `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser` to return null in this case.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the Toast message inside the "if" statement to show the UID of the user and it works. But firestore doesn't save the fields.

Comment: @AndreKool I tried moving it inside the onCompleteListener and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to your question you should post it as an actual answer. That way other people can more easely find it. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question :)